# Error - unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I don't know why I get this error, any tip?

I have already checked spaces/tabs:

```
if windll.user32.GetKeyState(Keybind_Use_Key_Code) >= 0:
        break
    DebugPrint("Sending Turbo Use Action")
    keyboard.press(Ingame_Keybind_Use)
    Sleep(0.020)
    keyboard.release(Ingame_Keybind_Use)
    sleep(Delay_Turbo_Use)
```

What do you think?

Comment: You really checked? Why does there exist three levels of indents? -- btw, use the `{}` button to format code block.

Comment: yeah I checked, I am not professional programmer I do this as hobby. Can you help to fix this ..

Comment: The lines starting from `DebugPrint` should be at the same level of `if`.  Read some more articles about indents in python please.

Comment: So, I must move DebugPrint at the same level of if and ? It's the first time that I meet this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the right indent should be like this:

```
if windll.user32.GetKeyState(Keybind_Use_Key_Code) >= 0:
    break
DebugPrint("Sending Turbo Use Action")
keyboard.press(Ingame_Keybind_Use)
Sleep(0.020)
keyboard.release(Ingame_Keybind_Use)
sleep(Delay_Turbo_Use)
```

Try this, see if it throws that error again.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. But I get a another syntax error but I think that I got it. Thanks about your time!

Comment: @PanosMrk Sure thing.